# Hourly list view in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to implement a simple calendar as my first Android app, but I don't know how I would go about implementing the daily view which consists of a `ListView` of all available hours, including those that have an event assigned to them.

Should I generate the empty hours and insert them into an `ListView`? Is there any better way?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking from a programming point of view, or a design point of view?

Answer (score 0):

You insert into your `ListView` what you want to show to your users.  If you want to show a row of empty case for those hours without an event then yes you put those hours into the `ListView`.  However, if you want to represent a collapsed view where only the hours with an event are shown then you don't include the other hours.

A good idea would be to represent only the hours with events but expand the list to dynamically include the other hours for the day when the user touch on it and vice-versa.

You could also use an `ExpandableListView` if you want to have something more like an hierarchy but using an `ExpandableListView` is not essential if you want to dynamically add or remove items to your `ListView`.